# HessianConnectionException: 500 Caused by: java.io.EOFException (Android)

Tags: android, hessian, eofexception

I'm using a hessdroid proxy to communicate between my android application and my webservice/hessianservlet. It works immediatly after starting the app, but when I wait a minute and let the app call a network function again (e.g. logout()) I get this error message:

```
com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianConnectionException: 500: java.io.EOFException
    at com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianProxy.invoke(HessianProxy.java:197)
    at $Proxy1.getPassword(Native Method)
    at tsch.serviceApp.net.DataHandler.getPassword(DataHandler.java:50)
    at tsch.serviceApp.PageSystemApps$1$1.run(PageSystemApps.java:91)
 Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:573)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:821)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:283)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:495)
    at com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianProxy.invoke(HessianProxy.java:167)
```

.

```
public String login() {
    HessianProxyFactory factory = new HessianProxyFactory();         
    String url = "http://192.168.56.1:8080/hessianServer";
    factory.setHessian2Reply(false); // avoid hessian reply error
    try {
        userCon = (IUserService) factory.create(IUserService.class, url+"/IUserService");                      
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Logged in!";
}

public void logout() {
    userCon.logout();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used [Flamingo](http://exadel.org/flamingo) instead of Hessdroid and everything works fine!

Answer (score 1):

I runned into the same problem on android 4.1 ,but it's ok on android 4.0.3. I added a statement " conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Close");" in method  openConnection of class HessianProxyFactory.

```
protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url)
            throws IOException {
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        if (_readTimeout > 0) {
            try {
                conn.setReadTimeout((int) _readTimeout);
            } catch (Throwable e) { // intentionally empty
            }
        }

        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "x-application/hessian");

        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Close");

        if (_basicAuth != null)
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", _basicAuth);
        else if (_user != null && _password != null) {
            _basicAuth = "Basic " + base64(_user + ":" + _password);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", _basicAuth);
        }

        return conn;
    }
```

and the problem disappeared.